# reusing a detached element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What I'm trying to do is after inserting a text in an h3 tag I am detaching it to remove it then I want to reinsert another text in the h3 tag but currently when I reinsert it the h3 tag has been removed so the text can't be inserted my question is 1. I thought `.detach()` can be reused again hence why I didn't use `remove()` why cant I simply reuse it. 2. How can I add my second text in the h3 tag after detaching. Im using h tag for this question to make it easier to understand. The only restriction is I have to use .detach() or something like that because the goal is to remove a playing video from dom and reinserting a different video. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
function foo() {
  $('#h31').detach()
}

function insert1() {
  document.getElementById("h31").innerHTML = 'this is inserted';
}

//what im tring to do
//but #h31 wont exist because it is detached 
//I tought detach() can be reused later
function insert2() {
  document.getElementById("h31").innerHTML = 'insert this again';
}
```

```css
#h31 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button onclick="insert1()">Insert</button>
<button onclick="foo()">detach</button>
<button onclick="insert2()">Insert again</button>

<h3 id="h31"></h3>
```

Comment: How about just hide/show it instead? Using detach() removes the element from DOM which is why you can't query for it again. To reinsert a detached object you need to store it in  variable and use an insertion method. It also won't know where it came from

Comment: I can't use hide/show because it's a video div so hiding it is just changing the appearance the audio is still playing though.@charlietfl

Comment: You can't pause() it?

Comment: won't that take too much background bandwidth? @charlietfl

Comment: I'm not a video expert but don't see why it would if it's not running